# Include jsx, js in a dot net standard nuget package?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have multiple ASP.Net Core Solutions (Web Sites) that I would love to share an entire directory of JSX files in each solution.  In the past, I added files to a locally hosted nuget package (.Net 4.7) and the files would distribute as content (I have seen this done with a readme.txt which is where I got the idea).  I tried the same approach adding files to a .Net standard dll (I was hoping to share with .net 4.7 and .net core... sweetness), mark the jsx files as content but when I add the local nuget package to my asp.net core web project, I get a "linked" type of icon [image: weird linked icon] and the file is not actually in the directory I expected.  Because the file is not "really" there, I can't include it from other jsx files that do exist in my actual web project.

I have tried Shared Projects, but that only shares in the same solution.  I have multiple Solutions in their own git repos.  I don't want to pay for private npm packages and I have seen people suggest against pointing to local git repos in npm package.json (this approach seems to be in my future).

My goal: create and maintain common reactjs components in a Solution/Project (jsx for now, I hope to move to tsx when I have time to get started) and by "any" (free) means, share those componenets with other Solution/Projects in different Solution/Web Project (different local repos).  I don't feel like this should be so uncommon.   I hope this is a simple matter of overlooking a simple solution... Thanks in advance!

Update: I tried this:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<Content Include="TestFolder/**/*.*" copyToOutput="true">
  <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
  <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
  <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
  <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

and the files are still "linked" in my target web projects.

Update 2:
Apparently my files are actually stored in the .nuget\packages\myPackageName\version\contentFiles\bla\bla folder.
How do I include my "shared via nuget" jsx files into my "project based" jsx files?  This linking thing makes sense, I just don't know how to use them yet.
I really don't want to use "include myControl from "../../../../../../../14 directories later/myControl.jsx"

Keep in mind that I am using npm and web pack to compile my components.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but I had to specify the target directory explicitly:

```
<file src="bundle.js" target="folder1/folder2/bundle.js" />
```

So reusing this is kind of limited. I had no such issue with linked files. The files are copied in the solution when I install the nuget.

**Note**: The nuget was plain JS (no .NET) and the target is not .Net Core (Net Framework 4.6)

Comment: I this is a "new" issue.  I tried creating/updating a nuspec file but I am building with Visual Studio 2017 and it seems to prefer adding files in the .proj file rather than the nuspec.

I added: 
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TestFolder/**/*.*" copyToOutput="true">
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
      <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
      <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
      <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

but in my destination, the files are still "linked"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning the nuget package route and switched over to TFS (on prem) npm package hosting via "TFS Packages"  It looks like nuget content (as jsx files) just isn't going to work.